# Using code script into a TIP or NOTE

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I'd need to include some code sections into the TIP or [NOTE] section of my asciidoc. Something like this:

```
TIP: you can use the following shortcut to find the process id:
[source,shell]
----
jps -lv | grep -i myserver | cut -d ' ' -f 1
----
```

I've observed that the shell script is correctly rendered but it fails to display the TIP section. (It just writes TIP: as plain text).
Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the alternate admonition-block formatting and the `--` block capture notation:

```
[TIP]
--
you can use the following shortcut to find the process id:

[source,shell]
----
jps -lv | grep -i myserver | cut -d ' ' -f 1
----
--
```

The `[TIP]` markup is just an alternative convention to the inline `TIP:` style. The opening and closing `--` marks capture multiple blocks as part of the admonition block. This works with other types of blocks, sometimes in conjunction with `+`, as with ordered or unordered list items.

Comment: Thanks a lot and apologizes for the delay in replying.